# Mysql query from one table with different conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to calculate every item's vote count for this table:

```
    user    item    vote
--------------------------------
    4       1       left
    4       2       left
    2       2       right
    3       2       left
    1       3       right
```

The result must be like this:

```
item | left_vote | right_vote
1       1               0
2       2               1
3       0               1
```

I've tried to use queries like this:

```
SELECT t.item, count(vote) as left_count, t.right_count  from (SELECT count(vote) as right_count, item from view where vote = 'right') as t, view where vote = 'left';
```

But it doesn't work. I think that I have to use join with subquery.

Is it real with mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL you can just use conditional aggregation:

```
select item, sum(vote = 'left') as left_vote, sum(vote = 'right') as right_vote
from votes v
group by item;
```

You don't need a join or subquery for this.